# How do I set my custom React component as a Type passed to the prop of another component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm making a `GenericModal` component with some custom styling. I want to pass an array of my `ModalText` components as props to GenericModal and have it display them.  I'd like to be specific that this is the type I'm passing rather than doing something generic like `React.FC`.

If I do

```
type Props = PropsWithChildren<{
    paneContents: ModalText[];
}>
```

I get an error `ModalText refers to a value but is being used as a type here. Did you mean typeof ModalText`.

If I use `typeof ModalText[]` then I get an error when I use it:

```
<View>
    {props.paneContents}
</View>
```

saying `TS2769: No overload matches this call. '(props: ViewProps | Readonly<ViewProps>): View', gave the following error. Type 'FC<Props>[]' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.`

Is there a way to do this? Or do I just have to use React.FC as the type and put in the comments that it's meant to be a ModalText?

**Edit**

Here's the ModalText component, if that helps:

```
type Props = PropsWithChildren<{
    style?: ViewStyle;
    header?: string;
    body?: string;
}>;

const ModalText: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
    return (
        <View style={[style.container, props.style]}>
            {props.header && <Text style={style.modalHeader}>{props.header}</Text>}
            {props.body && <Text style={style.modalText}>{props.body}</Text>}
        </View>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working exemple:

Let's say you have a component `App`, that calls a `ModalManager`. The `ModalManager` component receives an array of `Modal` components, that requires two props each: `id` and `text`.

You can type it with `React.ReactElement<IModal>`

This way, if you pass one `Modal` component with missing props or incorrect props, you will have a type error.

```js
interface IModal {
  id: number;
  text: string
}

interface IModalManager{
  modals: React.ReactElement<IModal>[]
}
  
function ModalManager({modals}:IModalManager) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>modal manager</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

function Modal({id, text}:IModal) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{id} - {text}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}


export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <ModalManager modals={[<Modal id={4} text="hi"/>]}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```